# Split array into 4-element chunks then implode into strings

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

I want output like

```
['1, 2, 3, 4', '5, 6, 7, 8', '9'];
```

Comment: Is there some logic behind the output you want? What have you tried? What stopped you from doing this yourself?

Comment: I wrote a logic but that was not working correctly. my logic is only joining the array with comma.

Comment: it's not clear. you checked `javascript` and `php` tags, without indicating why ! Which one  is  valuable for your question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_chunk()`](https://php.net/array_chunk) to split your array into chunks of 4 items. Then [`array_map()`](https://php.net/array_map) to implode() each chunk:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
$chunk = array_chunk($array, 4);
var_dump(array_map(fn($item) => implode(', ', $item), $chunk));
```

Outputs:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(7) "1, 2, 3, 4"
  [1]=> string(7) "5, 6, 7, 8"
  [2]=> string(1) "9"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that

```js
const $array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const $chunk = $array.reduce((r,v,i)=>
  {
  if (!(i%4))  r.pos         = r.resp.push(`${v}`) -1
  else         r.resp[r.pos] += `,${v}`
  return r
  }, { resp : [], pos:0 } ).resp


console.log( $chunk )
```

Comment: While the original question had the javascript tag, the sample input was provided via php syntax.  To improve the clarity of what little information was provided, I edited the tags to remove the javascript tag.

Answer (score 0):

For best efficiency in terms of time complexity, loop over the array only once.  As you iterate, divide the index by 4 and "floor" or "truncate" the dividend to form grouping keys.

When a grouping key is encountered more than once, prepend the delimiting comma-space before appending the new string value to the group's string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vs8jV))

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

foreach ($array as $i => $v) {
    $group = (int) ($i / 4);
    if (isset($result[$group])) {
        $result[$group] .= ", $v";
    } else {
        $result[$group] = "$v";
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

More concisely, you can split the array into 4-element rows and then implode those elements to form your delimited strings.  This has more expensive time complexity because it iterates more times than the number of elements in the input array. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vmFfE))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($v) => implode(', ', $v),
        array_chunk($array, 4)
    )
);
```

You could also consume the input array as you isolate 4 elements at a time with `array_splice()`, but this is probably the least advisable since it eventually erases all of the data in the input array. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CRXGf))

```
$result = [];
while ($array) {
    $result[] = implode(', ', array_splice($array, 0, 4));
}
var_export($result);
```

Output from all above techniques:

```
array (
  0 => '1, 2, 3, 4',
  1 => '5, 6, 7, 8',
  2 => '9',
)
```